# Удалить первые числа из строки

Tags: c#

Есть список из строк такого формата:

```
1 Это строка 1
25 Это строка 2
366 Это строка 366
```

Как можно удалить первые номера у строк. Мне нужно получить на выходе

```
Это строка 1
Это строка 2
Это строка 366
```

Comment: Добрый день. А в какой момент ваши попытки написать этот код зашли в тупик ? Давайте мы Вам подскажем. Добавьте ваш код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string Remove(string inp) => inp.Substring(inp.IndexOf(" ")+1);
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(Remove("1 Это строка 1"));
Console.WriteLine(Remove("25 Это строка 2"));
Console.WriteLine(Remove("366 Это строка 366"));
```

Вывод

```
Это строка 1
Это строка 2
Это строка 366
```

**UPD**

Вариант, если есть пробелы между числами

```
string Remove(string inp) 
{       
    for(int i=0; i<inp.Length; i++)
        if(char.IsLetter(inp[i]))
            return inp.Substring(i);
    return inp;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(Remove("1 46 456 465 Это строка 1"));
Console.WriteLine(Remove(" 434 43 25 Это строка 2"));
Console.WriteLine(Remove("333 3 3 3366 Это строка 366"));
```

Вывод

```
Это строка 1
Это строка 2
Это строка 366
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал по другому с помощью регулярных выражений

```
        private static string RemoveFirstNum(string inputString)
    {
        string outputString = null;

        //Поиск индекса первой заглавной буквы. 
        var result = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"[А-Я]").OfType<Match>().ToList().Select(a => inputString.IndexOf(a.Value, StringComparison.Ordinal)).FirstOrDefault();            
        outputString = inputString.Remove(0, result);            
        return outputString;


    }
```

Comment: Почему просто не воспользовались моим ответом? Какие преимущества у вашего?

Comment: Там по итогу оказались не только такие строки как писал изначально. Могли быть результаты с дублированием номеров, например 366 25 366 Это строка 366.

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ, проверяйте